# :hover is inconsistent and very jittery on absolutely positioned element

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have an absolutely positioned container that holds tag labels. These tags partially cover an image below them. When the user hovers over this container, I'd like for the tag labels inside the container to disappear.

The below almost works but the effect is inconsistent and very jittery when hovering over the container:

```css
.main-container{
  height:200px;
  width:100%;
  background-color:#ccc;
  position:relative;
}

.slider-tag-container{
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 22px;
    left: 20px;
    padding-top:30px;
    padding-right:30px;
}
.slider-tag-container .label{
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  margin-right:5px;
}

.slider-tag-container:hover  .label{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="slider-tag-container">
    <div class="label label-primary">Some tag</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/q2avqfqz/1/)

**Why does this "jittery-ness" occur?**

**How can I achieve the desired effect smoothly?**

Comment: You can't hover over elements that have `display:none`. Seems like you want `visiblity:hidden` maybe?

Comment: @CollinD I'm not hovering over the `display:none;` elements, I'm hovering over their parents

Comment: Perhaps give the parent a set height/width? I wonder if it's collapsing to `0px` wide and/or tall when its content is removed? Alternatively, does `:hover` bubble or not, might be worth checking into if hovering the child is causing the event to misfire when the child is then subsequently removed?

Comment: I think @CollinD has it figured out

Comment: @CollinD yeah, that's weird, in the Chrome inspector, the div appears to be taking up the expected space and shows the padding where it should be, but indeed, adding an explicit height and width does [make it much better](http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/q2avqfqz/2/). Thought there is still a bit of a jitter when coming up from the bottom. Thanks. Throw up an answer, and Ill accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the wrapper element a `min-width` or `width`. The inner element going  `display:none` is probably collapsing the wrapper to `0px` by `0px`.

Additionally, there may be an issue with `:hover` bubbling if you manage to get the cursor over the inside element before it triggers. I think a JS solution might be best here for more control over how it behaves.

Comment: You know, [I tried js using mouseenter and mouseleave](http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/q2avqfqz/3/) but still cant quite get rid of the jitter coming up from the bottom. Anyway, this is much better by far than it was, and I can live with the little quirk. Thank you.